# How to send keys to a process that started a bat file in C#?

Tags: c#, batch-file, input, process

This process starts a bat file that runs for a few seconds, after that I need to pass it a parameter for continue.

It is not possible to pass this parameter as an input parameter for the bat file.

This is as far as I go

```
 ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
 Process Process;
 ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
 Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
```

Now after a few seconds a menu is appearing and I have to input my choice to continue.

How can I do that?

Comment: OK so what did you try? did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

To send input to a process you use: Process.StandardInput

See full documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use WaitForInputIdle() if your process got a guid.

```
Process.WaitForInputIdle();
Process.StandardInput.Write("Someinput");
```